# UPS return service issue

Tags: php, ups

1. I am receiving the below error message after the implementation return service.

> Failure: Invalid merchandise description of package (120623)

Code what we used.

```
if (isset($return_order) && $return_order==1) {
  $returnService = new \Ups\Entity\ReturnService;
  $returnService->setCode(\Ups\Entity\ReturnService::PRINT_RETURN_LABEL_PRL);
  $shipment->setReturnService($returnService);
}
```

2. If I also use the below code then it gives as mention error

> Failure: Shipment/ReferenceNumber is not allowed for this shipment (120541)

Code what we used.

```
if (isset($return_order) && $return_order==1) {
  $referenceNumber->setCode(\Ups\Entity\ReferenceNumber::CODE_RETURN_AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER);
  $referenceNumber->setValue($shipping_reference_number);
} else {
  $referenceNumber->setCode(\Ups\Entity\ReferenceNumber::CODE_INVOICE_NUMBER);
  $referenceNumber->setValue($shipping_reference_number);
}
$shipment->setReferenceNumber($referenceNumber);
```

3. If I also use the below code then it gives as mention error

> Failure: Invalid merchandise description of package (120623)

Code what we used.

```
if (isset($return_order) && $return_order==1) {
    $referenceNumber->setCode(\Ups\Entity\ReferenceNumber::CODE_RETURN_AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER);
    $referenceNumber->setValue($shipping_reference_number);
} else {
    $referenceNumber->setCode(\Ups\Entity\ReferenceNumber::CODE_INVOICE_NUMBER);
    $referenceNumber->setValue($shipping_reference_number);
}
$shipment->getPackages()[0]->setReferenceNumber($referenceNumber);
```

I'm using the following package, https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-ups-api

Comment: Did you ask for help from the developers of the package?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Looks like they did: https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-ups-api/issues/363 (based on the user name and that it's word for word the same :-))

Comment: Did you check if this issue helped for one of your issues at least? [Shipment/ReferenceNumber is not allowed for this shipment (120541)](https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-ups-api/issues/333). Seems like it's a duplicate of some other issue that's been closed. Dig through their github issues (including closed ones) and see if you can find answers that way.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yes, I tried with that and it's giving me an "Invalid merchandise description of package" error. Where can I add "merchandise"? Did you guys have any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am passing the description on the package below. I just removed "box type" and it works like boom.

`$package->setDescription("box type : ".$box_type)`

Comment: Yes, that's why people ask for minimal-project reproducing the issue (no way for us to answer this).

Answer (score 3):

### The initial and last issue:

> "Failure: Invalid merchandise description of package (120623)"

Can be fixed by ensuring package properties are **all** correctly set, for example, if `$referenceNumber` is bar-code, try:

```
use Ups\Entity\ReferenceNumber as RefNum;

// ...

foreach ($shipment->getPackages() as $package) {
    $refNum = new RefNum();
    $refNum->setBarCodeIndicator(true);
    $refNum->setValue("MY_PACKAGE_BAR_CODE");

    $refNum->setCode(RefNum::CODE_SERIAL_NUMBER);

    // Alias (to match OP's naming).
    $referenceNumber = $refNum;

    $package->setReferenceNumber($referenceNumber);
} // foreach $package
```

> **WARNING:** I am not sure if `CODE_SERIAL_NUMBER` means bar-code, hence if that does not work, try other codes visible in [ReferenceNumber.php](https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-ups-api/blob/master/src/Entity/ReferenceNumber.php) file.

### The second issue:

> "Failure: Shipment/ReferenceNumber is not allowed for this shipment (120541)"

Means "`$shipment->setReferenceNumber(...);`" is not allowed for your request's type, hence don't do that (unless you are sure you need it).